# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n}+\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}+\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}+.......\sqrt[n]{(m-1)^n+m^n}}{m^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n}+\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}+\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}+.......\sqrt[n]{(m-1)^n+m^n}}{m^2} $$

the answer in the book is $\frac{1}{2}$ but i think the procedure of evaluating mis wrong so plzz solve this!

Comment: Are you missing an $n^\mathrm{th}$ root somewhere?  Otherwise the top term goes to infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try a double limit version of the squeeze theorem:

$$\sqrt[n]2\frac{(m-1)m}{2m^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2k^n}}{m^2}\le\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\sqrt[n]{k^n+(k+1)^n}}{m^2}\le\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2(k+1)^n}}{m^2}=\sqrt[n]2\frac{m(m+1)}{2m^2}$$

But

$$\sqrt[n]2\frac{m(m+1)}{2m^2}\xrightarrow[n,m\to\infty]{}1\cdot\frac12=\color{red}{\frac12}\;\;,\;\;\sqrt[n]2\frac{(m-1)m}{2m^2}\xrightarrow[n,m\to\infty]{}1\cdot\frac12=\color{red}{\frac12}$$

Comment: i didn't understand your first step

Comment: @sharafzaman I did $$2k^n\le k^n+(k+1)^n\le2(k+1)^n$$ and then extracted $\;n$-th roots in both sides

Comment: but how you equated  $\sqrt[n]{2}\frac{(m-1)m}{2m^2}$ with that summation

Comment: What is left in each summation is the sum of the first $\;m-1\;$ natural numbers (on the left), or one higher more on the right.

Comment: oh!!!!!!!!!! i got it $k=(m-1)m$

Comment: i denominator from where 2 popped up, it might be annoying

Comment: @sharafzaman Didn't understand you: for example, in the left side $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2k^n}}{m^2}=\frac{\sqrt[n]2}{m^2}(0+1+2+\ldots+m-1)=\sqrt[n]2\frac{(m-1)m}{2m^2}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36091/discussion-between-sharaf-zaman-and-joanpemo).

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution. By [the Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n}+\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}+\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}+.......\sqrt[n]{(m-1)^n+m^n}}{m^2}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(m-1)^n+m^n}}{m^2-(m-1)^2}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(m-1)^n+m^n}}{2m-1}\\
&=&\frac12.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @sharafzaman, I am glad you like it.